# How can I parse a YAML file from the web using PyYAML?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I need to get a YAML file from the web and parse it using PyYAMl, but i can't seem to find a way to do it.

```
import urllib
import yaml
fileToBeParsed = urllib.urlopen("http://website.com/file.yml")
pythonObject = yaml.open(fileToBeParsed)
print pythonObject
```

The error produced when runing this is:
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'open'

If it helps, I am using python 2. Sorry if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want `yaml.load(fileToBeParsed)` and I would suggest looking at `urllib2.urlopen` if not the `requests` module.

Comment: Thanks, it appeared to fix the problem.